# How to Query Multiple Values in two columns

Tags: mysql

I would like to check if two or more certain values like firstname and lastname is in my database.

```
Select * from client_info 
where (first_name = "John" and last_name ="Smith")
and   (first_name = "Donald" and last_name ="Trump")
and   (first_name = "Baracj" and last_name ="Obama")
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I understood your where statement but what row you want to select?

Comment: two or more certain values ?

Comment: I just want to check if john smith, donald trump, and barack obama is on client_info table inside the first_name and last_name columns.

Comment: That's a little clearer. Consider editing your question accordingly

Comment: if someone answered you well, mark it answered with green check mark. Thanks. By the way, adding indexes on for performance wasn't in the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can Try this:

```
Select * from client_info 
      where (first_name = "John" and last_name ="Smith")
           or (first_name = "Donald" and last_name ="Trump")
           or (first_name = "Baracj" and last_name ="Obama")
```

Comment: He said two or more and your query would return any one match of first_name last_name pair

Comment: I have run this and my sql command returns as many query as they matched firstnamae and lastname which are given in the query

Comment: I tried and it takes too long to query on a big database. Can you optimize this?

Comment: Does this work? I tried it and it just returns the pair matched by first condition.

Comment: If query takes too long, try to add index using first name and last name as one set.

Answer (score 0):

Execute this query and if result is >= 2 then you have both rows in a table

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT first_name, last_name FROM client_info
                      WHERE (first_name = "John" AND last_name ="Smith")
                         OR (first_name = "Donald" AND last_name ="Trump")
                         OR (first_name = "Baracj" AND last_name ="Obama")) AS ci
```